# Utilizar el if con arrays

Tags: c#

Para un trabajo de la universidad tengo que hacer un distribuidor. Ahora en una parte tengo que calcular cuantas monedas voy a devolver para dar el cambio.

Por ejemplo tengo una bebida agua que cuesta `€ 2.20`. La persona paga con `3` así que su cambio seria de `0.80`. El programa eso lo hace sin ningún problema.

Cuando la persona toma el pedido va ingresando (a través de un `listbox` que contiene los valores de cada moneda) cuantas monedas de cada valor recibe.

Y ahora yo tengo que calcular y mostrar cuantas monedas y el valor cuando voy a devolver el cambio.

Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente forma:

> - Hice 3 arrays
>
> 1 array bidimensional para guardar el valor de la moneda y la cantidad
>   de monedas de cada valor.
>
> Y un array simple decimal con posibles valores del cambio

`int posiblesValores []` (Lease aquí **bedragen**. Es un programa en holandés)

`posiblesValores= new decimal [19];`

y a cada uno le di estos valores:

```
bedragen[0]= 1.90m  ;
bedragen[1]= 1.80m  ;
bedragen[2]= 1.70m  ;
bedragen[3]= 1.60m  ;
bedragen[4]= 1.50m  ;
bedragen[5]= 1.40m  ;
bedragen[6]= 1.30m ;
bedragen[7]= 1.20m  ;
bedragen[8]= 1.10m ;
bedragen[9]= 1.00m  ;
bedragen[10]= 0.90m ;
bedragen[11]= 0.80m  ;
bedragen[12]= 0.70m  ;
bedragen[13]= 0.60m  ;
bedragen[14]= 0.50m ;
bedragen[15]= 0.40m  ;
bedragen[16]= 0.30m  ;
bedragen[17]= 0.20m  ;
bedragen[18]= 0.10m  ;
```

`Array bidimensional = decimal cambio[,]= new decimal [5,2]` (Cambio en holandés. **teruggave**)

```
teruggave[0, 0] = 2.00m;
teruggave[1, 0] = 1.00m;
teruggave[2, 0] = 0.50m;
teruggave[3, 0] = 0.20m;
teruggave[4, 0] = 0.10m;
```

Después entonces hice un método con `if` :

`wisselgeld` (valor a devolver)

Yo con esto intento que por ejemplo si el valor a devolver es igual a `1.90` entonces me muestre que tengo que regresar una moneda de `1`, una de `0.50` y dos de `0.20`.

El problema es cuando corro el programa para cada valor que tengo que devolver me da en pantalla lo mismo siempre que es el primer cambio del `if` osea como si valor a devolver siempre fuera `1.90`.

Ya verifique y el programa toma bien el valor del cambio y el valor del `array` de posibles valores y lo compara bien. Por ejemplo si es `0.30` el calcula:

`wisselgeld = 0.30`
`bedragen[0] = 1.90`

```
if (wisselgeld == bedragen[0]) //NO SE CUMPLE LA CONDICIÓN
{
    teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
    teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
    teruggave[3, 1] = 2;
}
```

(en `teruggave[0-5,1]` guardo las cantidades de monedas )

Mi pregunta es porque si compara bien y por ejemplo dice `0.30` no es igual a `1.90` el programa de la el valor al `array teruggave [ ,1]` como si este fuera igual. Es igual con cualquier valor de cambio. Siempre le asigna los valores al `array` como si si fuera igual a `1.90`.

Puede ser que haya otra forma de hacer esto y yo lo estoy haciendo muy complicado? por qué el `if` no me funciona aquí?

Este es el método con el `if`:

```
void TerugGaveBedrag()
{            
    if (wisselgeld == bedragen [0])
    {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[3, 1] = 2;               
    }
    else if (wisselgeld == bedragen [1])
    {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[3, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[4, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[2])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[3, 1] = 1;           
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[3])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[4, 1] = 1;           
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[4])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[2, 1] = 1;        
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[5])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;                
        teruggave[3, 1] = 2;                
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[6])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[3, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[4, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[7])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[3, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[8])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[4, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[9])
     {
        teruggave[1, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[10])
     {
        teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
        teruggave[3, 1] = 2;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[11])
     {
         teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
         teruggave[3, 1] = 1;
         teruggave[4, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[12])
     {
         teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
         teruggave[3, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[13])
     {
         teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
         teruggave[4, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[14])
     {
         teruggave[2, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[15])
     {
         teruggave[3, 1] = 2;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[16])
     {
          teruggave[3, 1] = 1;
          teruggave[4, 1] = 1;
     }
     else if (wisselgeld == bedragen[17])
     {
          teruggave[3, 1] = 1;
     }
     else 
     {
          teruggave[4,1] = 1;
     }   
}
```

Comment: Me equivoque en la pregunta no es for sino IF. No se como editarlo.

Comment: Justo debajo de la pregunta salen 3 enlaces [compartir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/217691/52028) [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/217691/edit) [reportar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/217691/utilizar-el-for-con-arrays#); de todos modos acá te deje el enlace de interés. Una pregunta en que momento llamas a la función TerugGaveBedrag()? no recibe parametros?

Comment: Buf. Creo que no has podido elegir una forma mas complicada de hacer una devolución de cambio en monedas. Lo que debes hacer es almacenar en un array las monedas disponibles, e ir dividiendo lo que debes devolver entre el valor de las monedas sucesivamente de forma descendente. Podrías usar una función recursiva, o simplemente con un sencillo bucle. Yo trataría de replantearme tu algoritmo a algo similar a lo que te he explicado.

Comment: porque programas tan complicado? lo que veo es que la variable wisselgeld  parece estar fija con un valor y comparas posiciones de bedragen, eso se puede realizar en un for, no se usa if, ademas asignas valores a posiciones de teruggave, la verdad que esta muy retorcido esa forma de programar, no te animas a pensarlo usando clases y listas ?

Comment: Otra cosa que te diria, es que por mas que tu programa sea en holandes trates de poner por lo menos para aca, las variables en español, si no es muy dificil seguirte.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a simplificar tu problema al maximo, porque estas tomando un rumbo totalmente complejo.

Para ello, solo tenemos que saber que tipo de monedas tenes y cuanto es el cambio que tenes que devolver.

Tu funcion, va a recibir la cantidad de cambio que necesitas (que dijiste que funciona y bien), y va a ir agregando monedas hasta que no le quede mas cambio por devolver.

Voy a respetar tu array de cambio (me parece perfecto si en la uni todavia no podes usar clases, listas o diccionarios)

```
teruggave[0, 0] = 2;
teruggave[1, 0] = 1;
teruggave[2, 0] = 0.50;
teruggave[3, 0] = 0.20;
teruggave[4, 0] = 0.10;
```

Y lo voy a usar en esta clase. Tene en cuenta, que antes de entrar la cantidad de monedas en el deberia estar en 0

Por lo tanto, deberias tener alguna función o algo que lo limpie antes (que haga `teruggave[0, X] = 0;` para todas las X)

```
public void DevolverMonedas(decimal ValorACalcular)
{
    int MonedaMaxima = 0;
    While (ValorACalcular > 0)
    {
        if (teruggave[MonedaMaxima, 0] <= ValorACalcular)
        {
            teruggave[MonedaMaxima, 1]++;
            ValorACalcular -= teruggave[MonedaMaxima, 0];
        }
        else
        {
            MonedaMaxima++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Cantidad de monedas de {teruggave[i, 0]} = {teruggave[i, 1]}");
    }
}
```

Analicemos la funcion

1. Declara MonedaMaxima, eso es para saber en que posicion del array de cambio estamos.
2. Mientra tengamos cambio por devolver, buscamos monedas.
3. Si la moneda es de un valor menor, agregamos una a esa, restamos el valor de la misma al cambio por devolver.
4. Si la moneda es mas grande, nos movemos en el array de monedas porque no nos sirve.
5. Mostramos el cambio a devolver al salir del while.

Fijate que si por ejemplo, entran 0.8, lo que pasa es lo siguiente

- en la primer vuelta, compara 0.8 con 2, le da mayor asi que solo hace MonedaMaxima++
- segunda vuelta, compara 0.8 con 1, le da mayor asi que solo ahce MonedaMaxima++
- tercera vuelta, compara 0.8 con 0.5, le da menor, suma 1 a la posicion de 0.5, resta 0.5 de 0.8, le queda 0.3
- cuarta vuelta, compara 0.3 con 0.5, le da mayor, hace MonedaMaxima++
- quinta vuelta, compara 0.3 con 0.2, le da menor, suma 1 a la posicion de 0.2, resta 0.2 a 0.3, le queda 0.1

Y ya te puedes dar una idea de como sigue.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @AdrianaRodriguez hace por favor el [tour] y fijate como funciona el sitio! se agradece el comentario, pero recorda aceptar las respuestas que te hayan ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu manera de intentar resolver el problema es sumamente compleja y no se adapta bien a cambios (por ejemplo, ajustar a monedas extranjeras con distinta división). Lo más fácil es escribir una rutina, llamémosla `ProducirCambio()`, que toma de parámetros la suma de cambio a devolver y un campo con las distintas monedas disponibles. La rutina llenará una dimensión del campo con la cantidad de cada moneda a devolver y lo hace utilizando un `for` loop, descontando del cambio a devolver el valor de cada moneda que se devuelve hasta que no queda nada.

```
// Parametros:
//  - cambio: monto a devolver en monedas.
//  - monedas: array de dos dimensiones de tamaño
//      [n, 2] donde n es la cantidad de monedas
//      distintas; [i, 0] debe contener el valor
//      de la moneda, [i, 1] deber ser 0 y será
//      cambiado a tener la cantidad de monedas
//      del valor especificado a devolver.
public static void
ProducirCambio(decimal cambio, decimal[,] monedas)
{
    // Ya no se usan monedas de €0,01 y €0,02 en
    // Holanda, por eso ajustamos el cambio a un
    // valor divisible por €0,05.
    int ajustado = (int)(cambio * 20M);
    cambio = (decimal)ajustado / 20M;

    // Pasar por cada valor de moneda y agregar
    // a la devolución las cantidades necesarias.
    for (int i = 0; i < monedas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        decimal m = monedas[i, 0];
        for (; cambio >= m; cambio -= m)
            monedas[i, 1]++;
        if (cambio == 0M) break;
    }
}
```

Esta rutina la podrías llamar así:

```
decimal[] monedas = new decimal[]
    { 2M, 1M, 0.5M, 0.2M, 0.1M, 0.05M };
decimal[,] devolucion =
    new decimal[monedas.Length, 2];
for (int i = 0; i < monedas.Length; i++)
    devolucion[i, 0] = monedas[i];
ProducirCambio(cambio, devolucion);
for (int i = 0; i < monedas.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{1} monedas de {0}",
                      devolucion[i, 0],
                      devolucion[i, 1]);
```

**EDIT:** Para demostrar la facilidad de introducir cambios en esta solución (*refactoring*), alteré la rutina `ProducirCambio()` de tal manera que toma sólo los valores del cambio y de las monedas como parámetros y devuelve el campo de dos dimensiones como resultado:

```
// Parametros:
//  - cambio: monto a devolver en monedas.
//  - monedas: array de los valores de las monedas
//      disponibles.
public static decimal[,]
ProducirCambio(decimal cambio, decimal[] monedas)
{
    // Ya no se usan monedas de €0,01 y €0,02 en
    // Holanda, por eso ajustamos el cambio a un
    // valor divisible por €0,05.
    int ajustado = (int)(cambio * 20M);
    cambio = (decimal)ajustado / 20M;

    decimal[,] devolucion =
        new decimal[monedas.Length, 2];

    // Pasar por cada valor de moneda y agregar
    // a la devolución las cantidades necesarias.
    for (int i = 0; i < monedas.Length; i++)
    {
        decimal m = monedas[i];
        devolucion[i, 0] = m;
        devolucion[i, 1] = 0;
        for (; cambio >= m; cambio -= m)
            devolucion[i, 1]++;
        if (cambio == 0M) break;
    }

    return devolucion;
}
```

Esta rutina la podrías llamar así:

```
decimal[] monedas = new decimal[]
    { 2M, 1M, 0.5M, 0.2M, 0.1M, 0.05M };
decimal[,] devolucion =
    ProducirCambio(cambio, monedas);
for (int i = 0; i < monedas.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{1} monedas de {0}",
                      devolucion[i, 0],
                      devolucion[i, 1]);
```